# How to dynamically define `prop`s on a `T::Struct` in sorbet at runtime?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have a struct that is defined as:

```rb
# typed: true
require 'sorbet-runtime'

class MyStruct < T::Struct
  MyPropType = T.type_alias { T::Hash[Symbol, Class] }
  
  class << self
    extend T::Sig

    sig { params(props: MyPropType).void }
    def register_props(props)
      props.each do |prop_name, prop_type|
        prop(prop_name, prop_type)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notice how `prop`s are defined at runtime.

Then somewhere in my codebase, at startup, I do `MyStruct.register_props({ foo: T.untyped, bar: T.nilable(T.untyped) })`.

Initializing `MyStruct` gives error when passing the codebase through typecheck. `MyStruct.new(foo: 'foo', bar: Bar.new)`.

```
$ ./bin/srb typecheck

/path/to/file.rb:66: Too many arguments provided for method MyStruct#initialize. Expected: 0, got: 1 https://srb.help/7004
```

How do I define `prop`s on `T::Struct` at runtime without the above typecheck error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `T::Struct`s cannot be defined dynamically (I mean they can but...), since the typechecker needs to statically know which props it's going to have. For this case I think you should use `T::InexactStruct`. See https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/master/gems/sorbet-runtime/lib/types/struct.rb

EDIT: Add snippet for future references

```rb
# typed: strict

class SomeStruct < T::InexactStruct
  extend T::Sig

  sig { params(props: T::Array[T.untyped]).void }
  def self.register(props)
    props.each do |name, type|
      prop name, type
    end
  end
end

SomeStruct.register [[:one, String], [:two, String]]

SomeStruct.new() # This would raise an error on runtime because of missing arguments, but not on static check
SomeStruct.new(one: '', two: '') # works on runtime, no static error
SomeStruct.new(one: '', two: 1)  # fails on runtime because of type mismatch, no static error
SomeStruct.new(one: '', two: '', three: '') # fails on runtime because of extra argument, no static error
```

Comment: It's absolutely correct that `T::Struct` and its props can not be defined dynamically! I don't see how I could use `T::InexactStruct` to achieve what I want to achieve. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Sure, take a look at this repo https://github.com/vaporyhumo/sorbet-inexact-struct-example. The gist of it is that `T::InexactStruct` doesn't statically typecheck, but does so at runtime.

Also, you can just get the file there and paste it on sorbet.run

Comment: Thank you so much for preparing that example.

Comment: But also: This is possible but please don't do this, you would be losing all the static typechecking that Sorbet is providing you.

Comment: @vaporyhumo do you mind adding your example to the actual answer for future references ?